# How to find a row content from a Pandas df into another df and then add the count of the findings into a new column of the first df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I just started using Python and I am trying to improve myself by engaging in different projects.

At the moment I am trying to create a work allocation tool. I loaded 2 xlsx files as df.

In df "dfau" there is a list of the employees with their capacity left and the languages that they speak.

| Employees | Capacity Left | Languages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E1 | 0 | EN, GER |
| E2 | -11 | EN, IT, ES |
| E3 | 6 | EN, CH |
| E4 | 2 | EN, ES, FR |
| E5 | -1 | EN |
| E6 | 1 | EN |
| E7 | -9 | EN, GER |
| E8 | 8 | EN, GER |

In df "dfln" there is a list of the languages.

| Languages |
| --- |
| EN |
| IT |
| ES |
| GER |
| CH |
| FR |
| NL |
| PT |

I would like to look for the languages listed in "dfln" into "dfau" and add the count of these languages as a second column in "dfln" (and this is where I am stuck).

Afterwards, in "dfln", I would also like to add a column which would show the capacity per each language by summing the capacities left of each employee which can speak the language.

The employees which have a "Capacity Left" below 1 should not be counted nor summed.

This is how it should appear:

| Languages | Count | Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EN | 6 | 85 |
| IT | 0 | 0 |
| ES | 3 | 15 |
| GER | 1 | 8 |
| CH | 1 | 6 |
| FR | 1 | 2 |
| NL | 1 | 45 |
| PT | 2 | 13 |

I tried to re-write the code in different ways but still this is where I got stuck (the result remains the basic dfln.

```
import pandas as pd
dfau = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Projects\pywp\SampleAu.xlsx', sheet_name='Employees')
dfln = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\Projects\pywp\SampleAu.xlsx', sheet_name='Languages')
    
LCount=0
dfln.insert(1,"Count",LCount)
    
for language in dfln["Languages"]:
    if dfau.loc[dfau["Languages"].str.contains(language, case=False)] is True:
        LCount+=1
    print(dfln)
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Please, post code and data, not image of such.

Comment: Hi James, apologies, it was my first post and i m not familiar yet. I hope now it's more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot make sense of the final output. However, you can achieve what you are asking by running the following code:

```
dfIn['Count'] = 0
dfIn['Capacity'] = 0

for idx,row in dfIn.iterrows():
    dfIn.iloc[idx,1] = dfau['Languages'][dfau['Capacity Left'] >= 1].str.contains(row.Languages).sum()
    dfIn.iloc[idx, 2] = dfau['Capacity Left'][dfau['Capacity Left'] >= 1][dfau['Languages'].str.contains(row.Languages)].sum()
```

Notice that the final output looks like this, and not what you posted above:

[image]